# Typescript: An object with any amount of keys or values

Tags: typescript

I am trying to make a store function and set up types for each instance that I want to make. So I started with the following:

```
interface Store<Value> {
    get: () => Value,
    set: (n: Partial<Value>) => void
}

const createStore = (initialStore: any) => {
    let store = initialStore

    const get = () => store

    const set = (newStore: any) => {
        store = {
            ...store,
            ...newStore
        }
    }

    return {
        get,
        set
    }
}

const defaultOptions = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
}

interface Options {
    x: number,
    y: number | null
}

const options: Store<Options> = createStore({...defaultOptions})
```

But obviously if you were to do the following typescript would allow it but it would be problematic.

```
const store = createStore('hello')

options.set('ho')

console.log(store.get())
```

You would run into problems logging something like this:

```
{
  "0": "h",
  "1": "o",
  "2": "l",
  "3": "l",
  "4": "o"
}
```

But if I specify `Object` or `object` to the createStore function like `const createStore = (initialStore: object) => {}` then I get an error:

```
Type '{ get: () => Object; set: (newStore: any) => void; }' is not assignable to type 'Store<Options>'.
  The types returned by 'get()' are incompatible between these types.
    The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
      Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'Options': a, b
```

So how do I make sure that only an object is passed through but with any type of keys and values?

I have also tried

```
interface StoreArgs {
    [key: string]: any
}
```

I get the following error

```
Type '{ get: () => StoreArgs; set: (newStore: any) => void; }' is not assignable to type 'Store<Options>'.
  The types returned by 'get()' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'StoreArgs' is missing the following properties from type 'Options': a, b
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could utilise generics and then specify that the type `extends` object on the `createStore` function.

For example:

```js
const createStore = <T extends object>(initialStore: T): Store<T> => {
    let store = initialStore

    const get = () => store

    const set = (newStore: Partial<T>) => {
        store = {
            ...store,
            ...newStore
        }
    }

    return {
        get,
        set
    }
}
```

This will let you call `createStore` with any value that extends 'object' as you want rather than strictly saying that the `initialStore` value MUST be only an object.

Comment: Sorry I presumed that was a typo when you posted the code, the issue there is that `Options` specifies the properties `a` and `b` where the object you are passing through specifies `x` and `y`. Is that intentional? Edit: Your comment just disappeared, leaving for posterity sake.

Comment: Ya it was a typo I tried to delete the comment quick but I guess it still went through. This code works on ts playground but not in my project so I am trying to figure out why I am getting an error on my local machine now.

Comment: So this works if you don't have an `|` in the type. So if I do `interface Options {x:number y: number | string}` then I get the following error ...in next comment

Comment: Type 'Store<{ x: number; y: number; }>' is not assignable to type 'Store<Options>'.
Types of property 'set' are incompatible.
Type '(newValues: Partial<{ x: number; y: number; }>) => void' is not assignable to type '(newValues: Partial<Options>) => void'.
Types of parameters 'newValues' and 'newValues' are incompatible.
 Type 'Partial<Options>' is not assignable to type 'Partial<{ x: number; y: number; }>'.
Types of property 'y' are incompatible.
Type 'string | number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number | undefined'.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.

Comment: At this point you'll either need to pass `Options` when you create the store, eg. `createStore<Options>({ ... })` or you need to specify that your `defaultOptions` is of type `Options` eg. `const defaultOptions: Options = { ... }`. Bare in mind you can remove the explicit typing of `const options = ` and just allow typescript to infer the type from the function call.

Comment: Thanks. I've been trying to force myself to learn typescript and there is still some things I don't quite understand about it so thanks for all of your help.